# DLNA and Web Sockets no longer work on my PC

Tags: windows-10, dlna, websocket

I run Windows 10 Home Edition with 4GB Memory. About a week ago my computer started acting up and here are the issues:

1. The text in document folders are larger than normal but the files remain the original size.
2. I can't stream DLNA over my home network. When I try to access video/music from my PS4, it doesn't play at all.
3. Finally, web sockets doesn't work on websites I get on. A buddy and I are working on a project but strangely I can't access content that's called through web sockets, everything else works fine but sockets doesn't display any data to me.

I think it was from some sort of update on my PC because everything works for everyone else, but I keep getting these issues. Number 1 is random, it happens time to time. However 2 and 3 are recurring.

P.S I have PC security in case anyone was curious, so no viruses/malware.

Comment: Did you try disabling your PC security to see if a firewall is blocking it?

Comment: Yes I have. I currently have Eset and I disabled both that and my main firewall, but nothing was fixed.